# date difference getdate () - yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My table has an date column 'orderdate' with type as yyyy-mm-dd 
I want to get the date difference against getdate()

```
select getdate() - orderdate from table
```

this should return the number of days

Comment: Read up about `datediff()`. Note - I am a different Raj :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Need to use this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,orderdate,GETDATE()) FROM table
```